# Can I be sure that the next time React renders it will use the most recent state value?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

There are lots of places in the React docs where it says that a React may enqueue a batch of state changes and do them all the once later.

[React Component Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

> **setState() enqueues changes to the component state** and tells React
>   that this component and its children need to be re-rendered with the
>   updated state. This is the primary method you use to update the user
>   interface in response to event handlers and server responses.
>
> Think of setState() as a request rather than an immediate command to
>   update the component. For better perceived performance, React may
>   delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React
>   does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

[React Hooks API Reference](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate)

> **Basic Hooks - useState**
>
> `const [state, setState] = useState(initialState);`
>
> Returns a stateful value, and a function to update it.
>
> During the initial render, the returned state (state) is the same as
>   the value passed as the first argument (initialState).
>
> The setState function is used to update the state. It accepts a new
>   state value and **enqueues a re-render of the component.**

**QUESTION 1**

My question is: regardless of how many state updates React decides to enqueue to perform on a single batch, can I rely on the fact the next render will use the most current state with all the updated that were queued since the last render?

**QUESTION 2**

Can I rely on the order of those state changes that React decides to queue? I mean, If I `setState({a:1})` and then `setState({a:2})` can I be sure that the final value of my state will be `2` ?

Comment: interesting questions, from my own experience if you execute your setState synchronously then the next time it renders all the states will be new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Question 1: No, React can render (for instance) only half of the update queue, and THEN the other.

Question 2: Yes. The order in which the updates are processed might not be as simple as the order you call `setState` in, but in the end, the insertion order is what determines the latest version of your state.

Detailed explanation in the [react code](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/7ad7386308abd55f12ad9f1cddac6a97860e92eb/packages/react-reconciler/src/ReactUpdateQueue.js#L10).